# Selenium - Cannot reach frame in NodeJS

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I cannot reach the highlighted frame with the below:

```
await driver.switchTo().frame("main");
```

[image]

I have also tried:

```
let frameElem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/frameset/frame[2]"));
await driver.switchTo().frame(frameElem);
```

What am I doing wrong? All documentation I have come across demonstrates this as working but it is not working for me.

Any input will help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
await driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
await driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

For some reason, I had to switch to the default and then select frame(1).

Hope this helps someone with the same problem as me.